# parsing a character date time format in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to parse a column into two variables, "date" and "time" in R. I have installed the `lubridate` library.

The current csv file has the following timestamp format: `yyyyMMdd hh:mm a` (e.g. `'20170423 12:26 AM'`) and imports the column as character.

I'm trying this but its not working on my current variable `'Tran_Date'` (below code doesn't work):

```
transactions_file <- as_date('Tran_Date', "%Y%m%d %H:%M %p")
```

Comment: Your variable name should not be in quotes. Also the base function name is `as.Date()` that takes `a format=` not `as_date()` which does not take a format string. `Tran_Date <- '20170423 12:26 AM'; as.Date(Tran_Date, "%Y%m%d %H:%M %p");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the base R solution like this,

```
Tran_Date <- as.POSIXct("20170423 12:26 AM", format = "%Y%m%d %I:%M %p")
Tran_Date
#> [1] "2017-04-23 00:26:00 CEST"

transactions_file <- data.frame(
     date = format(Tran_Date,"%m/%d/%Y"),
     time = format(Tran_Date,"%H:%M")) # possibly add %p if you use %I
transactions_file
#>         date  time
#> 1 04/23/2017 00:26
```

with `lubridate`,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(lubridate)

Tran_Date <- ymd_hm("20170423 12:26 AM")
```

then you could recycle the above or use some combination of `day(Tran_Date)` `cbind` `paste` with `month(Tran_Date)` and similar with `paste(hour(Tran_Date), minute(Tran_Date), sep = ":")` or most likely something smarter.

Comment: @DoctorG, did this answer solve your issue? It's good if you mark the question as answered if it did indeed answer your question.

Comment: Yes, it did. And I just read up on and learned about the check-box. Thx!